# put character count and character type limit for the textfield swift 4

Tags: swift, uitextfielddelegate

I would like to put a limit for textfield. Example: Max character count should be 6 and characters can be digits only. But i could not put these two controls in one function.

First func for count of the text:

```
func textFieldCharacterCountLimit(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let maxLength = 6
    let currentString: NSString = txt_phone_no_verification_code.text! as NSString
    let newString: NSString =
        currentString.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as NSString
    return newString.length <= maxLength
}
```

Second func for type of the text:

```
func textFieldCharacterTypeLimit(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet.decimalDigits
    let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
    return allowedCharacters.isSuperset(of: characterSet)
}
```

Beside this, it gives an error also. And textFieldCharacterCountLimit function does not work. I think i get an error because two functions effect same textfield with return. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just make up delegate method names. You need to implement the proper method and do all of your needed checking in the one method.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let newString = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    if newString.count > 6 {
        return false
    }

    return newString.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted) == nil
}
```

Comment: This works without any extension. That's why it is better if i mark this as a reply to my question. By the way, i did not know this: "You can't just make up delegate method names." Thank you for this detail also.

Answer (score 1):

**Allowing only a specified set of characters to be entered into a given text field with specific range**

```
   func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if string.count == 0 {
            return true
        }
        let currentText = textField.text ?? ""
        let prospectiveText = (currentText as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

        return prospectiveText.containsOnlyCharactersIn(matchCharacters: "0123456789") &&
            prospectiveText.count <= 6

    }
```

**String extension with condition**

```
extension String {

    // Returns true if the string contains only characters found in matchCharacters.
    func containsOnlyCharactersIn(matchCharacters: String) -> Bool {

        let disallowedCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: matchCharacters).inverted
        return self.rangeOfCharacter(from: disallowedCharacterSet as CharacterSet) == nil
    }
}
```

> How to program an iOS text field that takes only numeric input with a maximum length
>
> > http://www.globalnerdy.com/2015/04/27/how-to-program-an-ios-text-field-that-takes-only-numeric-input-or-specific-characters-with-a-maximum-length/